# how (multiple=true) presenter and view can be initialized with parameters using eventBus.addHandler?

Tags: gwt, mvp, mvp4g

With the Mvp4g architecture, (Only)one instance of the view (injected using @Presenter annotation)is associated with its presenter.
   In my case, I have a EntityView with its Presenter EntityPresenter.
   whenever user clicks on an Leaf node of a Navigator tree, 
   I add a new Tab into TabSet. And this new Tab will contain an EntityView.
   So, I will have as many EntityView as many Tab in the TabSeT.

I have set `multiple=true` for EntityPresenter.
   EntityView's constructor accepts one argument.

```
@Inject
public EntityView(final Record view) {
  //some initialization
}
```

Question is, where I do (from another presenter):

```
EntityPresenter presenter = eventBus.addHandler(EntityPresenter.class);
```

I have one argument `Record params`  which I want to pass to EntityView's constructor, how to do that?
   and annotating constructor(accepting argument) with @Inject will inject EntityView to EntityPresenter ?

Comment: have some clue here http://groups.google.com/group/mvp4g/browse_thread/thread/71efe128ec7c9ec3?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use an `EventHandler` - that's a presenter without a view in mvp4g - which get an event showEntity(long key). In the onShowEntity(...) - method you can create the presenter with the statement:

```
EntityPresenter presenter = eventBus.addHandler(EntityPresenter.class);
```

With that reference of the instance, you can esaly set the key in the presenter.
But keep in mind, you have to manage your presenter instances by yourself, when using `multiple=true.`